# Make certain li float right in Wordpress menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to make the phone and e-mail float to the right in the menu.

Why is this not working?:

```
li.menu-item30, li.menu-item29  {
float:right!important;
}
```

Wordpress, Responsive Theme by Cyberchimps.

Comment: It working for me when I add `float: right;`.

Comment: There is `-` hyphen between `menu-item` and `29`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names were not correct, the following worked for me.

```
.menu-item-30, .menu-item-29  {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thx! I totaly missed that :)